# Copy files according to file name list and dir list to a new location, but keep the directories structure

Tags: python, directory, operating-system, copy, shutil

I'm working on copying files according to a file name list and a directories list.

The file name list,

food.txt:

```
apple.png
kiwi.png
bacon.png
croissant.png
```

Those png files are located under the following directories:

dirs.txt:

```
C:\image\fruit\
C:\image\meat\
C:\image\bread\
```

For instance: apple.png and kiwi.png are under C:\image\fruit\, bacon.png is under 
C:\image\meat\, etc.

I wrote code to copy the files from their original locations to a new one, according to the file name list text file and dir list text file.

My Code of copying the png files:

```
import os
from shutil import copy

food_file="C:\\food.txt"

new_folder= "C:\\newfolder_for_food\\"

dirs = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open("C:\dirs.txt")]

with open(food_file) as foodNames:
    food_list = fileNames.read().split('\n')
    for i in food_list:
        for f in dirs:
            file_path = os.path.join(f, i)
            if os.path.isfile(file_path):                    
                copy(file_path, new_folder)
                print("Copying, Please Standby...")
print("Executed!")
```

However this would put all pngs under C:\newfolder_for_food\

I want apple.png and kiwi.png being under C:\newfolder_for_food\image\fruit\, bacon.png being under  C:\newfolder_for_food\image\meat\, etc. But I'm not sure how to do it. Can anyone help to modify my code?

Thanks in advance!

Poppel

Comment: You can do it with a single bash command: `cp -rf former_folder new_folder` (or the windows equivalent )

Comment: Use "os.path.splitdrive" to remove driveletter, remove leading "os.pathsep" character(s) and "os.path.join" target path with this.